# Jquery's Ajax with CORS not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm having a hard time trying to make work a simple jQuery's Ajax between two domains.

When I try to execute Ajax in site A, in the developers tool's Network section I get '404 Not found' in the GET methods related with Site B.
I also see this message in the console: "...missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

In "site A" I've this:

```
<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", "http://domainB.com/resource.php", true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log('Connected!');
    };
    xhr.send(null);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domainB.com/resource.php',
    }).done(function ($result) {
        //somecode
    });
</script>
```

And in the resource's server ("Site B"):

```
<?php    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
    //somecode
```

This is my first time with CORS and I really have no much idea what's wrong.

Thank you

Comment: there is a little trick as a cors everywhere addon in Mozilla Firefox addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere but this is temporary solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer in this post:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/.
It seems that the problem was in my Ajax code, I just added some properties and now it's working perfectly.
This is how my Ajax looks now:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
        }).done(function ($result) {
            //somecode
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code at start of php page

http://domainB.com/resource.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-  Size, 
X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

Comment: It didn't work, with your code I received this error on the domainB.com/request.php: "Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in http://domainB.com/resource.php on line 7", and I'm still getting this error in the domainA console: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://domainB.com/resource.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."